# Unwrap optional as conditional object that implements an interface

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement a function that called conditionally if the optional object returned by a function implements a particular protocol.  I'm struggling with the syntax ... it's telling me:

```
Braced block of statements is an unused closure
```

and

```
Expected { after if condition
```

Example:

```
class SomeType {
}

class Something {
    func doSomething()
}

protocol Foo {
    func foo() -> SomeType
}

class Bar {
    var whatever : SomeThing
}

extension Bar {
    var handler : SomeThing? {
        return whatever
    }
}

class FooBar {
    func doSomething(bar : Bar) {
        // Assuming that bar's handler is set and implements Foo then use foo...
        let foo = bar.handler as SomeThing : Foo {
            ...
            foo.doSomething()
            ...
            foo.foo()
        }
    }
}
```

I could do this:

```
if let foo = bar.handler! as? Something {
    if (foo is Foo) {
        foo.doSomething()
        (foo as Foo).foo()
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
if let fubar = bar.handler! as? Something, let foo = fubar as? Foo {
    fubar.doSomething()
    foo.foo()
}
```

But I'm hoping there's a cleaner way

Comment: `bar.handler as? Foo`? That only will work if `Foo` doesn't use `Self` and doesn't have associated types, though.

Comment: @zneak Assume that it doesn't.

Comment: Doesn't what? Doesn't have associated types and doesn't use Self?

Comment: @zneak Yes.  Your comment is tangential to the question.  It doesn't matter how `Foo` is used, I'm just trying to get hold of an instantiation of `Something` only if it implements `Foo`

Comment: @zneak Edited the question to hopefully make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: It boils down to what type you expect `foo` to be and what guarantees you expect to have from the type system in that scope, and that's still unclear. Swift doesn't let you express a type that extends a given class and also implements a given protocol.

Comment: @zneak Isn't that exactly what where clauses are for?

Comment: If you're referring to generic where clauses, they work in generics, but they can't be used in an if statement.

Comment: @zneak I think you can use `where` in `let` statements since 1.2?

Comment: That `where` clause lets you test more conditions on unwrapped variables, not on their types. You'd be doing, for instance, `if let someInt = foo() where someInt > 5`.

Comment: @zneak This seems to be the cleanest way: `if let foo:Something = bar.handler! where foo is Foo` although the compiler still needs you to cast `(foo as Foo)`.  Your comment that the where clause is just a condition solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the cleanest way to do it.

```
if let foo:Something = bar.handler! where foo is Foo {
    foo.doSomething()
    (foo as Foo).foo()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear from this code exactly what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to do this fully dynamically (deciding everything at runtime) you're likely fighting Swift. It's often possible, but at every turn you're going to be fighting the language's paradigm. The way you generally handle what you're describing is with overloads so that this is determined at compile time rather than runtime:

```
func doSomething<F: Foo>(handler : F) { ... things when F is Foo ... }
```

Mixing a lot of classes + generics + protocols this way is often a source of great pain, so you should be asking carefully why `Bar` is a class and not a struct (and at least why it's not a `final class`). It's difficult to give exact advice from highly this kind of highly stylized question, so a little more structure about the problem you're trying to solve may help.

All that said, you can generally do what you're describing. Your syntax is just incorrect. What you seem to mean is:

```
    if let foo = bar.handler as? Foo {
```

Comment: Rob, I've edited the question to show two examples of I'm trying to avoid.  I'm hoping there's a way I can get a single object that is an instantiation of `Something` but only if it implements the protocol Foo

Comment: That's a common question. The answer is no. You need to put whatever methods you want from Something and Foo into a protocol and then require that protocol.

Comment: The situation is I have a class `A` that has a number of subclasses, only some of which implement the protocol.  A container class has a member variable of type `A` that in practice is more often one of the subclasses.  Your solution would be impractical.

Comment: Then you will likely have to redesign. "Is a subclass of X and conforms to a protocol" is a type requirement that is very commonly requested, but cannot currently be done in Swift.

Comment: The container class is UIViewController and the parent class is UIView, some of the child classes of which - as you're aware - implement a number of different protocols.

Comment: if the answer is "There is currently no clean way to do this", that's fine too.